# Split order by seller

Tags: order-splitting

Please, someone can indicate some module that will split the order.
I need to split orders based on vendor id.

I found some references on the internet, but none of them resolved.

Comment: wich version of magento is?

Comment: is version 2.4 of magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Free extension.But you may need to customize it according to your needs.

https://www.magetop.com/magento-2-split-order-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

You has 2 posibilities

1.- Create store by vendor(subdomain or path, like store.com/seller_1, store.com/seller_2), and shared same inventary for all stores, filter in grid ALL Stores by ID store ,

2.- Create attribute checkout called seller_id, and POST send with campaign of seller , add attribute to filter